# Maintain Checkbox status between PageIndex

Tags: c#, page-index-changed

Seems as if I am missing something simple.
Checked boxes do not retain status when changing PageIndex.

.aspx page

```
    <asp:Panel ID="ReassignPanel" runat="server" Width="100%" >
    </asp:Panel>
```

code behind

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class TasksReassign2_aspx : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvTasksList.Visible = true;
            DropDownList ddlAssignedTo = (DropDownList)ReassignDetailsView.FindControl("ddlUserAssignedToSelection");
            ddlAssignedTo.DataSource = DropDownSource_AssignedTo;
            ddlAssignedTo.DataBind();
            for (int i = 0; i < ddlAssignedTo.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ddlAssignedTo.Items[i].Text = ddlAssignedTo.Items[i].Text.Replace(" (inactive)", "");
            }
            DropDownList ddlReassign = (DropDownList)ReassignDetailsView.FindControl("ddlUserReassignSelection");
            ddlReassign.DataSource = DropDownSource_ReassignTo;
            ddlReassign.DataBind();
            ddlReassign.SelectedIndex = ddlReassign.Items.IndexOf(ddlReassign.Items.FindByValue(usr.UserID.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private void CheckboxSave()
    {
        ArrayList array_Tasks = new ArrayList();
        for (int index = 0; index < gvTasksList.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            bool result = ((CheckBox)gvTasksList.Rows[index].FindControl("cbReassign")).Checked;
            if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
            {
                array_Tasks = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
            }
            if (result)
            {
                if (!array_Tasks.Contains(gvTasksList.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text))
                {
                    array_Tasks.Add(gvTasksList.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                array_Tasks.Remove(gvTasksList.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text);
            }
        }
        if (array_Tasks != null && array_Tasks.Count > 0) ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = array_Tasks;
    }

    private void CheckboxPopulate()
    {
        ArrayList array_Tasks = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        if (array_Tasks != null && array_Tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < gvTasksList.Rows.Count; index++)
            {
                if (array_Tasks.Contains(gvTasksList.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text))
                {
                    CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)gvTasksList.Rows[index].FindControl("cbReassign");
                    chkbx.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void paging_gvTasks(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckboxSave();
        gvTasksList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvTasksList.DataBind();
        CheckboxPopulate();
    }    
    /****************************************************************************/
    protected void evaluateCheckChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rblOption.Text == "T") //Taks
        {
            gvTasksList.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Text);
        }
    }

    protected void Changed_AssignedTo_or_rblOption(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlAssignedTo = (DropDownList)ReassignDetailsView.FindControl("ddlUserAssignedToSelection");
        ddlAssignedTo.DataSource = DropDownSource_AssignedTo;
        UserTasksGridSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
        gvTasksList.Visible = false;
        if (rblOption.Text == "T")
        {
            gvTasksList.Visible = true;
            LabelHeaderTasks.Text = "Task(s)";
            UserTasksGridSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
            UserTasksGridSource.SelectParameters.Add("Users_PKID_assigned", TypeCode.Int32, ddlAssignedTo.SelectedValue);
            UserTasksGridSource.SelectMethod = "Tasks_GetListByUsers_PKID_assigned_to";
           UserTasksGridSource.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching the Page Index of a GridView causes a postback. Unless you are storing and loading the checkbox value between postbacks, you need to use an UpdatePanel (AJAX) and the appropriate AsyncPostbackTrigger.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

UPDATE:

Sorry, I should have read your example code. I did not realize that you were storing the checkbox values.

However, looking at your code in the `paging_gvTasks`, I do not think it will work. The page will re-load before it gets to the paging event. Breakpoint your Page Load and paging events. Then change the page of the GridView and watch what happens.

Page Life Cycle: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That code is in the CheckboxSave and CheckboxPopulate procedures.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I have taken this code from @ least 4 different excerpts. Am I doing the databind wrong, calling the populate code @ wrong time? All data is being compiled correctly. It is just not POPULATING the GridView correctly.

Comment: It appears as though it is loading the page after the paging event. I believe it should save current checks, load new page then mark "checked boxes" from stored "checks"

Comment: @1968PontiacGTORagtop Put the CheckboxPopulate() in the page load.